# BeautifulSoup to crawl Tables with and without an ID in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I am trying to crawl websites and they all have tables. However, the first url has a table ID called `.table-translations` and the other one doesn't have an ID thus it doesn't crawl.

But if I don't include it, it wouldn't crawl.

How do I use BeautifulSoup to crawl the data with and without a table ID?

below is my code

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


urls = ['http://www.mongols.eu/mongolian-language/mongolian-tale-six-silver-stars', 'http://www.mongols.eu/mongolian-language/mongolian-tale-yanzin-jaal']

for url in urls:
        print(url)
        out_fileName = url.rsplit('/', 1)[-1]
        out_mn = out_fileName + "_mn.txt"
        out_en = out_fileName + "_en.txt"

        soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content, 'html.parser')

        all_data = []
        for row in soup.select('.table-translations tr')[1:]:
                mongolian, english = map(lambda t: t.get_text(strip=True), row.select('td')[1:])
                all_data.append((mongolian, english))

        for row in all_data:
                with open(out_mn, "a") as text_file:
                        text_file.write(row[0] + "\n")
                with open(out_en, "a") as text_file:
                        text_file.write(row[1] + "\n")
```

Comment: I only see one `<table>` on the page... can you please edit your question and put there expected output?

Comment: @AndrejKesely yeah so the post has correct info. The first one has Table class ID but the other one doesn't have one.

Answer (score 0):

This script will get all translations from these two URLs. But if there other pages with different structure, it needs adjusting:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


urls = ['http://www.mongols.eu/mongolian-language/mongolian-tale-six-silver-stars', 'http://www.mongols.eu/mongolian-language/mongolian-tale-yanzin-jaal']

for url in urls:
    print(url)

    soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content, 'html.parser')

    all_data = []
    for row in soup.select('tr')[1:]:
        tds = [*map(lambda t: t.get_text(strip=True), row.select('td'))]
        if len(tds) == 3:
            mongolian, english = map(lambda t: t.get_text(strip=True), row.select('td')[1:])
        else:
            mongolian, english = map(lambda t: t.get_text(strip=True), row.select('td'))

        print(mongolian)
        print(english)
        print('-' * 80)
        all_data.append((mongolian, english))
```

Prints:

```
http://www.mongols.eu/mongolian-language/mongolian-tale-six-silver-stars
Зургаан мөнгөн мичид
Six silver stars
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Эрт урьд цагт зургаан өнчин хүүхэд товцог толгой дээр наадан суудаг юм санжээ.
Long ago, there were six orphan brothers playing on the top of a hill.
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

... and so on.
```